# Can anyone make an iOS todo app recommendation

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation

I am looking for a todo app that does the following:

- reoccurring daily tasks
- reminders via push notifications, if they aren't completed
- sync lists between multiple devices, and preferably multiple users
- some sort of log that shows when and who completed a task

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com/en/) meets all your requirements.

Comment: I was looking at that application earlier today, it seemed like there was a subscription required for sharing lists. Is that correct? I don't mind buying an app, but I don't really want to subscribe to a service.

Comment: You can share lists for free, you just can't attach files or use the conversation feature.

Comment: Thanks been using this over the weekend and it is working pretty well.